# How to check if Toplevel window is opened?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know if `Toplevel` window is opened or closed by the user manualy, with only one open button for opening the window. I tried to do it with `winfo`, but for some reason it doesn't work properly.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

global top
top= None
global counter
counter = 1
global root
root = None

def window1():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    root.title('Window1')
    my_button = Button(root, text="Open Window", command=openWindow2)
    my_button.pack(pady=50, padx=50)

    root.mainloop()

def openWindow2():
    global counter
    if (counter < 2):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.geometry("300x200")
        top.title('Window 2')
        my_label = Label(top, text="New Window!", font=("Helvetica, 24"))
        my_label.pack(pady=50, padx=50)
        counter +=1
    else:
        checkwind2()

def checkwind2():
    if (top is not None) and Toplevel.winfo_exists(top) == 1:
        #this situation never happens
        print("Window is opened")
    else:
        print("Window is closed")

window1()
```

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish in the `checkwind2()` function — or in general. One problem with your code is that you are not using `global` statements correctly. They are only needed in functions that want to *change* the value of a variable not local to themselves (i.e. it prevents a local variable with the same name from being created).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you put `global`s in the wrong place and so the `top` variable always appears to be `None`.
If you want to edit a variable outside a function, you need to add `global` **inside** the function.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

top= None
counter = 1
root = None

def window1():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    root.title('Window1')
    my_button = Button(root, text="Open Window", command=openWindow2)
    my_button.pack(pady=50, padx=50)

    root.mainloop()

def openWindow2():
    global top
    global counter
    print(counter)
    if (counter < 2):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.geometry("300x200")
        top.title('Window 2')
        my_label = Label(top, text="New Window!", font=("Helvetica, 24"))
        my_label.pack(pady=50, padx=50)
        counter +=1
    else:
        checkwind2()

def checkwind2():
    if (top is not None) and Toplevel.winfo_exists(top) == 1:
        print("Window is opened")
    else:
        print("Window is closed")

window1()
```